# Creating a site programmatically in Netlify with NuxtJS using NetlifyAPI

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to automate website deploys in Netlify using the Netlify REST API and I keep getting this error:

```
 These dependencies were not found:                                 friendly-errors 07:27:07
                                                                   friendly-errors 07:27:07
* node:buffer in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
* node:http in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
* node:https in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
* node:net in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/utils/referrer.js
* node:stream in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
* node:url in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/request.js
* node:util in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/body.js
* node:zlib in ./node_modules/netlify/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
                                                                   friendly-errors 07:27:07
To install them, you can run: npm install --save node:buffer node:http node:https node:net node:stream node:url node:util node:zlib
```

Tried both:

```js
import { NetlifyAPI } from 'netlify'
```

and

```js
import NetlifyAPI  from 'netlify'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to downgrade the "netlify" package version to v.9.0.0

Comment: It says I need to wait 2 days in order to accept my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is why I said "when you can".